# Pivottable in Excel. How can I order value in a column in progressive more

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table in Excel with a column representing the week number.
If I do sort in Alphabetical order I will get 1, 10, 11, 12 ... 2, 20, 21 etc.

This is not making sense. How can I get a 1,2,3,4... order?

I was looking into creating a "custom filter" with no success.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you are storing numbers as text. if this is the case, then  it is sorting in the correct order, try converting to numbers or adding 0 for example 00001 , 00002,00010,00020

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your source data column is formatted as General:

- Go to source data
- Right-click on column
- Select Format Cells
- Select General
- Click OK

If you get green arrows in the upper left corner of each cell, then convert the text to numbers:

- Click on the first cell
- Drag the mouse down to the last cell (it won't work if you use keyboard shortcuts like shift+ctrl+down)
- Click the yellow diamond icon
- Select "Convert to Number"

After you have accomplished the above, refresh your pivot table and sort the field.